# Service Fabric Debugging with CodePackageDebugParameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, azure-service-fabric

When a new service fabric application is created inside VS the default template adds debugging magic to the scripts so that an application running inside service fabric can be debugged. The powershell scripts passes the `_WFDebugParams_` as application parameters to the cluster. I can't figure out to get it working in code. The code I'm currently using is

```
var debugParameters = new CodePackageDebugParameters(
   "MyApplicationPkg", 
   "Code", null, null, 
   "Main", 
   @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\VsDebugLaunchNotify.exe", 
   "{625F9A8A-16A1-42E6-948F-D5D9AF04F1AB} -p[ProcessId] - tid [ThreadId]",
    null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
nameValueCollection["_WFDebugParams_"] = CodePackageDebugParameters.GetDebugParameters(new[] { debugParameters });

await app.CreateApplicationAsync(new ApplicationDescription(ApplicationName, ApplicationTypeName, ApplicationTypeVersion.ToString(), nameValueCollection)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I have only VS2017 installed on my machine with the remote debugger tools. My questions are the following:

- What path should be used for the VsDebugLaunchNotify?
- How is the GUID
  determined (I currently paste in a random GUID as debug parameters)?

Another problem that I have is that `CodePackageDebugParameters` is basically unusable. I had to copy paste the whole class definition into my project because the ctor and all the properties are internal.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I want to run integration tests from within the cluster using nunit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, the GUID is a correlation id of a named pipe set up by Visual Studio Debugger. It is later used by Service Fabric Cluster to ping VS back with process id and thread id that it should auto-attach to.

Here is the more detailed explanation of what is happening when you hit F5 in Visual Studio (Please note that this is a result of investigation done on my local dev environment and might not be 100% accurate as parts of this is not covered by documentation for VS or SF):

1. Service Fabric Extension scans solution that is about to be debugged and lists all SF services to be deployed into local cluster
2. For each service it runs `StartListener` method using undocumented debugger interface `IVsDebugLaunchNotifyListenerFactory110`. So if there are x services in the project there will be x notifiers started
3. This in turn creates a named pipe called `MicrosoftVisualStudioProcessLaunchNotify_{<<GUID>>}` where the GUID part is generated for every function call
4. Service Fabric Extension deploys SF application passing the GUID in `_WFDebugParams_` as indicated in the question.
5. During service startup, SF uses the `_WFDebugParams_` to run `VsDebugLaunchNotify.exe` passing the GUID, ProcessID of service that was started and ThreadID debugger should auto-attach to.

NOTE: It looks that `StartListener` can only be used from inside the Visual Studio Extension.

Answer (score 0):

Service Fabric Tools uses this *WFDebugParams* parameter, so when service fabric application that is being debugged can attach to VS debugger. It is not meant to be used by end user.

Comment: Are you saying when I don't use the F5 experience of Vs and deploy my application with code I just can't debug the applications in that easy way? I mean of course I can manually pick the process hosted in SF and then attach the debugger but this feels off especially when there is already an existing solution.

Comment: May I know the scenario that you are trying to code? From the question, it seems like you are trying to replicate the VS F5 scenario. To your specific question on guid, it is not any random guid, it a generated by the debugger so the service fabric service process can call back and attach to the right debugger.

Comment: @RavikumarPalanisamy if the scenario is the following - deploying an application that is deploying via C# API another application to the cluster and the need to debug the "nested" deployed via code app/service.

Comment: What @seanfeldman said. Is there a way I can programatically create the right GUID?

Comment: Within the VS extension, IVsDebugLaunchNotifyListener110 should be started first. This listener will have information about the GUID. So, it is not possible to generate the GUID unless you have access to the listener.